# Can I use source command in aliases?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to create bash scripts. I would like them to run in my current shell so that, for instance, when I create a directory I want to be redirected into the new directory without having to type cd and the path of the new directory.

All my scripts are saved in a bin folder in my home directory.
This is an example of a bash script called test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir /path/of/the/directory

cd /path/of/the/directory
```

Is it a good practice to create an alias and use source command in the alias like below?

```
alias ="source $HOME/bin/test.sh"
```

Thank you very much in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Thats absolutely fine. For example, I have an alias in my .bashrc that sources .bashrc:

```
alias rebash='source ~/.bashrc'
```

Comment: I can see how you might want an alias for sourcing `.bashrc` but in the general case, having an alias to source each of a set of library files with interactive functions is ... just weird.

Comment: @tripleee: Depends on what his real question is? ;-)

Comment: thanks very much tripleee and NaN for your replies. Basically the idea is to create a script to set up everything for my React and React-Native projects so that's why I used a separate file to put all the commands in it and I want to use it in my current shell (by using source) and be redirected automatically in the folder.  of the project

Comment: @xapgo: Then it should be fine. Especially if you want to set some environment variables for your current shell.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is absolutely no reason to do that.

This sounds vaguely like you should be creating a function which contains the code, and not have an alias or an external file at all.

```
g () {
    mkdir -p /path/of/the/directory
    cd /path/of/the/directory
}
```

Put this in your `.bashrc` or similar.  Maybe if you want it in a separate file, create a file `$HOME/bin/interactive.bash` and then just `source $HOME/bin/interactive.bash` from your `.bashrc`.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I do not want to change the mkdir command. It was just a example. The main point of the script (set up React project) is that when it is finished I am redirected to the folder I just created. That's why I wanted to use source. I thought about the alias so that I do not have to write all the time `source nameOfTheBashFile.sh` or `./nameOfTheBashFile.sh cd nameOfFolder` every times I want to run the script. It is mainly a laziness issue ;-)

Comment: @xapgo ok it was interresting in case, the current working dir belongs (as environment) to process and when process exits it can't change change current directory of caller this can only be done by caller indeed

Comment: "absolute no reason"?  "Usually" is the better word. For example, I use this: `alias reload-bashrc='. ~/.bashrc'`

Comment: "No, there is absolutely no reason to do that.". I completely disagree. I have a current situation requiring this. I have a script at a funky path. I need to dotsource that script. I want to have an alias (or function) in my .bashrc that points at that path so that I can run that script (with the long funky path) on demand. So, I need to dotsource the alias (or function) that calls this script. I have not found a way to do this, and there is absolutely a reason to do this. Does anyone know how an alias / function can be dotsourced in this way?

Comment: Save it in a separate file if you need to update it on demand. If not, a function in your `.bashrc` which you write once and then use as you need should work fine as well, although you'll probably also want to evaluate it on the command line as well when you originally create it.

Comment: ok, I get it, tried it, thanks, that works. 

Answer (score 0):

It is fine if you use `source` in an alias.

However, as a general practice, you should define all your aliases in `~/.bash_aliases` and source them in `~/.bash_profile` using `source ~/.bash_aliases` so that once a new shell is launched it will load all the available aliases.